# Направить трафик клиента через другой интерфейс и пробросить порт

Tags: linux, сеть, iptables, vpn, wireguard

Маршрутизатор Keenetic. Есть интернет от провайдера, и на роутере поднят WireGuard.
Интерфейсы:

- `br0 192.168.2.1` - интернет
- `nwg1 10.100.218.11` - vpn wireguard

Нужно весь трафик локального клиента с адресом `192.168.2.64` направить через wireguard впн `nwg1`. Но при этом пробросить порт `31555` из интернета `br0` на локального клиента `192.168.2.64:21555`.

Пробовал через маркировку пакетов:

```
iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -s 192.168.2.64 -p all -j MARK --set-mark 65
ip rule add fwmark 65 table 555
ip route add default dev nwg1 table 555
```

Трафик идёт через впн, но проброс порта, не работает:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 31555 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.2.64:21555
```

Видимо, из-за правила в `mangle prerouting`.

Познания iptables не очень, все через гугл.

Answer (score -1):

Нужно включить переадресацию трафика на уровне ядра :
`echo 1 | sudo tee /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward`

Чтобы настройка сохранялась после перезагрузки :
`sudo sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1`

`iptables -A FORWARD` ...
далее нужно добавить правила ESTABLIHED и RLEATED